# Using bootstrap template in TinyMce

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tinymce

I have html page, created in bootstrap 3 (page.html).

After copy html code in TinyMce editor (Source code option), I can see all page content but without css/js settings (colums,tabs,accorditions,etc..).

Now, is there some solution to see all bootstrap features in TinyMce editor?

Tnx